# Creating RSS item list using KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, rss

This is my first time posting so hopefully, someone can help me out (and my description is OK). I'm starting (and enjoying) to learn Python, Kivy & KivyMD and I'm a bit stuck trying to create a list from an RSS feed.

When I run the code I am able to see only one headline and not a list of the headlines like I'm trying to get.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
import feedparser
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, ThreeLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

d = feedparser.parse('https://news.google.com/news/rss/?hl=en&amp;ned=us&amp;gl=US')
for post in d.entries:
    headlines = (post.title)
    url = (post.link)
    date = post.published



class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
         
        scroll = ScrollView()
        list_view = MDList()
            
        items = ThreeLineListItem(text=str(headlines),
                                  secondary_text=str(url),
                                  tertiary_text=str(date))

        icons = IconLeftWidget(icon="android")

        items.add_widget(icons)
        list_view.add_widget(items)

        scroll.add_widget(list_view)
        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```

This is the output

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8rum.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are speaking about the "headlines" variable inside for loop,

```
    for post in d.entries:
        headlines = (post.title)
        url = (post.link)
        date = post.published
```

Here the headlines variable gets updated during every iteration of the for loop, and finally headlines will give you the value for its last iteration. If you want to save the values in a list during every iteration,

```
headlines = []
for post in d.entries:`enter code here`
    headlines.append(post.title)
    url = (post.link)
    date = post.published
```